# Must declare the scalar variable "@levelID"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE st_ getPeriodWRTTimings
    @levelID int
AS
    SELECT
        t.t_id AS 'ID', p.p_name + '(' + t.t_dayName + ')' AS 'Periods' 
    FROM
        timings t
    INNER JOIN 
        periods p ON p.p_id = t.t_pid 
    WHERE
        t.t_levelID = @levelID
```

Comment: What is your question? Your post has no context: it just looks like random characters to me.

Comment: Please share the C# that is calling this stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

there is a space in your proc name , which I think its a typo, change it to `st_getPeriodWRTTimings` and you will be fine.

however if you want have space in your proc name (not recommended) you can use bracket like this:

```
create procedure [st_ getPeriodWRTTimings] ...
```